# Rebuilding the WHOLE Java application everytime I make a change

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, testing, war

I am new to building Java web applications & WAR files.  I am working with a fairly large web application that is built on Java & JSP pages.  We have a ANT file that will re-build the entire application every time a single change was made.  I want to know if it is possible to only re-build the part of the application that was modified instead of the whole entire project.

Testing is a 10 minute process because I will make a change, shutdown Tomcat, run the ANT script, start Tomcat, re-load application in browser which now takes 7min to do load for the first time after a re-build (I'm also curious to know what it's doing here?)...Basically complete hell for testing.

If anyone could suggest a better testing strategy I would be awesome!  Also maybe anyway we would just have the ANT script re-build only modified classes.

Comment: Separate your project into different libraries, then you will just have to rebuild the components that were modified. If the problem is that you just have to modify the web application itself (e.g. a JSP, a JavaScript or something in your Servlet/Controller classes), then you're out of luck. By the way, knowing that time is precious and you must pay a lot for every change you make, then make the proper changes and not a 1-line change to test if the change works/it doesn't.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks! that sounds like a plausible solution.

Comment: You could always debug tomcat itself, with the WAR in question being deployed. It will require a custom tomcat installation, an unzipped WAR, and some trickery withing your IDE to convince it that the tomcat project has sources in all the other projects you have open (so that you can step debug and use hot code replace). Also, you will need to replace the JSP files within the deployed WAR with links to the JSP files in your main projects for autoreloading to work - end enable autoreload in tomcat, ofc. In general, not for the faint of heart, and it may invalidate your purpose - testing...

Comment: "I'm also curious to know what it's doing here?" - Well, since your site has to recompile each time you make a change in a Java file, you are experiencing what is called 'spin-up'.  The site is basically re-compiling and preparing to render itself.  This also happens with C#/ASP.NET web applications too.

Comment: If this is the case, how is Java better than PHP (or any other server side interpreted language)? If I want to test my PHP, I can simply refresh the page. With Java, I have to recompile the whole damn project and sit there for 6 minutes to test one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things one can do.

1. One can modify jsp in the tomcat/temp directory.  The change will be available immediately without any recompiling/reloading
2. One can use the remote Tomcat debugging (from Eclipse). This debugging allows one to change the source code and this change will be propagated to Tomcat immediately
3. The best way to organize your ant script is to separate compiling into several jars and then creating a war file. Then recompilation for one change will happen only in one jar.
4. It is not required to restart Tomcat under redeployment if you specify reloadable=true for the context

Comment: Thanks for the list! Would options 2,3 or 4 avoid the 'spin-up' that @Brian is referring to?

Comment: I did not completely understand about spin-up.  Reloading without restarting Tomcat may result in out-of memory problem especially with big applications on not powerful servers.  Therefore in production we restart Tomcat in most of the cases.  However, for testing a potential memory problem is not so important.  After a while one can get feeling how many times reloading works without causing the memory problem.  Tomcat 7 can be better for memory management than predecessors.